# Where is docker proxy configured?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my terminal error when i want to use `docker-compose up --build`.

```
=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9                                                  0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM python:3.9
   2 |     
   3 |     ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: python:3.9: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.9": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2080: connect: connection refused
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

i want to solve this error and remove this proxy config `proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2080` but i can not find the file,

There is nothin in `/home/cc/.docker/config.json` and `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`

I can use pip in my system outside of docker.

I am using `Xubuntu 22.04` and `docker 24.0.7`, how can i find this config?

Answer (score 1):

I find another file in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf` and proxy was set here.

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:2080"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:2080"
```